# Error "Failed to open TCP connection to localhost:35729" on Rails app on a Docker container

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker, ruby-on-rails-4

I am having getting an error message "Failed to open TCP connection to localhost:35729 (Cannot assign requested address - connect(2) for "localhost" port 35729)" when I start my Rails local server on my Docker container by foreman start. I tried to access the server on "localhost:5000". The rails server is configured to be hosted on port 5000 on the localhost.

As for the docker container, I started it from an image by running a docker command

```
docker run -it --name <my-container-name> -p 5000:5000 -p 35729:35729 -v <host_project-directory>:/home <image-name> /bin/bash
```

in order to bind the port 35729 on the docker container with the host's port 35729. The port 5000 is where this rails application is configured to run the local server, so I also bound it with the host.

I also confirmed the ports are bound to the local machine by starting the container and run

```
docker port <my-container-name>
```

which gave me

> 35729/tcp -> 0.0.0.0:35729
>
> 5000/tcp -> 0.0.0.0:5000

So I'm guessing it is not the problem with port binding.

Why am I getting this error message even though the port is open on the Docker container and is bound to the host machine? I appreciate any advice to be able to connect to the local server running on the container from the host machine.

Notes:
Rails Version: 4.2.11.1
Docker container: Debian GNU/Linux 9

[image: Error page]

Comment: What service is running on port 35729; what code is trying to connect to it?  When you say "on the localhost", is that the physical system or the container (which both separately think `localhost` is "me")?  Can you include a [mcve]?

Comment: Need docker to figure it out

Comment: Thanks for the response! I meant my own machine(physical system) for the "localhost". I'm trying to clone one of my projects my student organization has (not a tech company), and to set up a dev env using the repository. I'll check what's running on 35729 and update you soon

Comment: @Goma0925, I'm getting same error using Docker - Puma caught this error: Failed to open TCP connection to localhost:35729
Did you manage to fix this?

Comment: Found issue in /etc/hosts
Fixed by 
**cp /etc/hosts /etc/hosts.new && \
sed -i 's/::1\tlocalhost ip6-localhost ip6-loopback/::1 ip6-localhost ip6-loopback/' /etc/hosts.new && \
cp -f /etc/hosts.new /etc/hosts**

ref: https://github.com/locomotivecms/wagon/issues/340